# Link GDAL library using CMake instead of g++

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, gdal

I wrote a program that reads a GeoTiff file with GDAL. To compile it, I write:

```
g++ my_program.cpp -lgdal
```

However, I want to run this code with Clion. How do I add this `-lgdal` to the CMake file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-l` is an indication to the linker to link the `gdal` library to your executable, so the corresponding CMake command is [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html). So your CMake might look something like this:

```
add_executable(MyExecutable my_program.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyExecutable PRIVATE gdal)
```